# iOS Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, opengl-es, out-of-memory

Is there anyway to find out Exactly Why iOS is kicking out the app for a memory issue like this?

We are tracing down an issue with Open GL and are having problems finding out what in Open GL is causing iOS to kick our app after a bit.

Yes, we are using Instruments for memory allocation (regular memory allocation is fine) and Open GL tracing, so far nothing is standing out.

Comment: Do the instruments show memory leak?

Comment: Turns out that this was something of a GPU Texture issue and the number of OpenGL Sessions.  We backed of the number of sessions and cleaned up the code a bit.  It was working with SKVideoNode until iOS 10, then had to get rid of SKVideoNode.